# Add global function to every execution of NodeJS

Tags: node.js

In my project folder `project` I have a file `utils.js` like this

```
global.root_path = process.cwd();
global.custom_require = function() {
    console.log('custom require called');
}
```

I would like to include this file in every execution of node so that in every js file in `project` i can call `custom_require`, or access `global.root_path` as I'm doing already with built-in function `require`.

Do you know if there is a solution (command line options, environment variable or whatever) to achieve this?

**UPDATE** 
I don't want to include `utils.js` in every file, in that case I wouldn't need to modify `global` object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `require` it. Example `app.js`:

```
require('./utils.js');

var express = custom_require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port);
```

Then, you could just do (in terminal)

```
node app
```

As long as you `require` the code containing the global declarations on it, then you can use those globals from any file that's `require`d after the fact.

You most probably don't want to have a custom "plugin" altering the behavior of all your applications when run locally, thus it'd be best to stay away from that kind of pattern. Instead, you might want to create a module, use `npm link` on it, and then `npm link something` in your project's directory, where `something` is the module name.

Then each project could just add one line like `require('something');` at the very beginning. Changing `something` would immediately impact all the projects which included it, thanks to the behavior in `npm link`.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, I edited the question. Requiring that file means that I need to know where it is located, relatively to the file I'm working on.

I would like to have those global data as it's built in in node (Avoiding modify and recompile nodeJS from scratch :) )

Comment: If you make it into a module and use `npm link` as I described, you wouldn't need to know the relative path to that file, you could just `require` it using the module name like any other package. See [npm link](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html).

Comment: Sorry I didn't read carefully your answer. I played a little with `npm link` as you suggests and discovered that it's what I'm looking for.
Do you know if there is a way to to a npm link on every subfolder of my project? (I mean , without a script :))
Thanks dude!

Comment: why would you need to do it on every folder? just give a  `package.json` to the module you're going to include for the global type stuff, and then you can `npm link` on the directory containing that. Then, in any given project, do `npm link {name}`, where _{name}_ would be the name you gave to the module in its `package.json`

Comment: This code must be loaded on many machines and I cannot manually do a `npm link`, that's why I need an automatic way to link globally all the modules I write.

Comment: Can you publish the module on `npm`? That'd be the logical way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately not because it's private. Since `npm link` looks in `node_modules` folder I can easily write a script to loop dirs inside and link them